# Using php function in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to call a php function in javascript. I have one solution, which actually works, but not the way i would like.

code:

```
function test(){ 
    document.getElementById("php_code").innerHTML="<?php   
    print 'something';
    ?>"; 
}

... 
<a href="#" onclick="test(); return false;"> test </a>
```

It works when i click on the link, but i can't call the funciton in other way, just by clicking on the link.
So what i would like, to call the function simply by test()

Comment: I hope you know that the PHP part is executed on the server, before it is sent to the browser and the JavaScript is executed. You could simply write `document.getElementById("php_code").innerHTML='something';` in your JavaScript, since this is what the browser gets. Regarding `test`: You can call at anywhere just with `test();`.

Comment: JavaScript gets executed on the client, PHP gets executed on the server. You can't call a php function from JavaScript.

Comment: have a look at AJAX. I think there is no different solution since php is executed before the clients get the page.

Comment: why is this question being downvoted? Obviously he did not know that it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

learn AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript And Xml), as javascript is executed AFTER the PHP. With AJAX you can without refreshing the page send a request to the server, and the server returns some string then, which you could use on your page. (By sending some parameters with the request you can execute the test() function (if you convert it to PHP) with a simple if-statement.)

Comment: This should actually be a comment. Or else, give a good explanation why it isn't possible, how you can use a different path, probably with resource (own example) or a summary.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed on serverside (it is responsible for rendering the page for the browser), meanwhile Javascript will be executed clientside (after th page has been delivered to the browser).

So the only way, you could pass values between them, is the one of your solution. Calling functions between them is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible.

PHP is server-side code and Javascript is client-side. The only method of executing a PHP script from javascript call is via AJAX. There is a very simple tutorial to get you up and running with AJAX on w3schools.

[w3schools Ajax Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)